# SQL SELECT from Local Client Connection Retrieving Server Data With Path

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server, file-locking

We've been using [Advantage Database Server](http://advantagedatabase.com) 9.1 (Netware) with DBF/CDX index files successfully for several years, via the Delphi `TDataSet` descendant components. (This is legacy data required for statistics/reporting purposes.)

A couple of weeks ago, we switched from Netware to Win2K8 as our network operating system, and moved to ADS 9.1. This broke the functionality of queries from the local client that perform `SELECT` queries against server databases.

For instance, the below query worked fine with the Netware version of ADS 9.1 in ARC32's SQL window, running with a local connection to free tables in `C:\Data`:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyLocalDB 
  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [\\MyServer\Data\MyRemoteDB.dbf] WHERE somecondition
```

The same query worked using a mapped drive to the server's directory instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyLocalDB 
  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [S:\Data\MyRemoteDB.dbf] WHERE somecondition
```

Note that it's a [free table](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/devguide_free_tables_versus_database_tables.htm) - it's not part of a data dictionary. It's a free table in a location that has read/write access to the folder on the server where it's stored. The local client connection's folder is fully accessible (it's used for testing applications on a daily basis, using a local connection to the data). A normal application can run on the client against either the local connection data or the remote connection data without any issue. It's **only** the query from a local connection to retrieve server data that's a problem, and it was working correctly before. The only difference was the switch from Netware to Win2k8 for both the OS and ADS, and according to the documenation (see quoted help file content below) it should still work.

After the switch to the Windows version of ADS 9.1, both of the above queries fail with

> Error 7008: The specified table, memo file, or index file was unable to be opened. Table name \MyServer\Data\MyRemoteDB.dbf (or S:\Data\MyRemoteData.dbf).

We upgraded to ADS 10.10 on our system this week (and to the ADS 10.10 `TDataSet` 10.10 components as well), but the above queries still fail.

Is this simply not supported under the Windows version of ADS? The documentation makes it seem like the first one should work:

> Drive letters in paths of table names can only be used with Advantage Local Server. When using Advantage Database Server for NT or NetWare, fully qualified paths must use UNC (e.g., "\server\volume\path\table"), because the SQL statement is parsed at the server where client-side drive letters are not meaningful. Note that tables referenced like this must be enclosed in double quotes or [] (brackets) because they contain non-standard characters.

The UNC path is properly surrounded with `[]` brackets, and there are no spaces anywhere in the path or table name. I've tried with and without appending the `.dbf` extension; the error message remains the same.

Comment: Does Advantage still use a data dictionary for schema?

Comment: @ltn: Advantage has never "used a data dictionary". It's an option that's been available the last few versions, but not using them is still just as viable. The reference to `free table` in my question indicates it's not in a data dictionary. :-)

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for the formatting assist. I keep forgetting to check and see if the normal formatting needs a language boost. :-)

Comment: The reason I asked is because if your problem is corruption you could try removing/adding the table to advantage.

Comment: @ltn: The problem isn't corruption. Applications can directly open the file on the server, and I can use a server connection to open it directly. The issue (as stated in the title) is that queries from a local connection to retrieve server data doesn't work, and did with other versions of ADS. The data and indexes are fine. (You can't just `xcopy` files from the server to a local folder any more, and sometimes a subset is needed to test something. The easiest solution was to open a local client connection and `INSERT` using a `SELECT` from the server data to get the local copy.)

Comment: @ltn (continued): In addition, the file is already "in Advantage". There's nothing to be "in" except a folder on the server. It's a **free table**, in a folder full of other **free tables**. See [this link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/devguide_free_tables_versus_database_tables.htm) for info. If you're not familiar with ADS, perhaps you should skip this question. :-)

Comment: Ok...I extended the advantage TADSDatabase and TADSDataset components  in a Delphi a while back. I guess the architecture has changed a bit.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but, do you have an ads.ini file? I found this [link](http://www.thissucked.info/?tag=advantage-data-dictionary-cannot-be-opened) regarding error 7077 (opening data dictionary) that might give you a hint. I know your error is 7008 but it seems the problem might be the connection as well.

Comment: NTFS Permissions? Does the account that the ADS server/service is running under have appropriate perms to open the DB? <Suck-eggs-mode>Don't forget that both the server\share [Everyone: Full control] AND the actual NTFS directory [Users/groups as appropriate] need to be readable. And knowing DBF tables there probably needs to be access to a writeable area for temp files too.</Suck-eggs-mode>

Comment: @Guillem: Yes, I have an ADS.INI file, but it only stores connection info. The two in question (`Development`, which is to `C:\Data`, and `Production`, which is to the server UNC) both work fine if you do the query from within the connection SQL window. IOW, I can query data in `Development` fine from that connection. There's no data dictionary involved, as I've mentioned before - it's a **free table**.

Comment: @Shunty: No, it's not NTFS permissions. I can open the files fine (I can run an app on my local machine that uses a remote connection to open files on the server with either the mapped drive or a UNC path, and things work fine. It's simply when trying to SELECT server data from a local connection that it fails. We read and write files fine, there is a writeable temp file location for the server and client both, and things work fine for every other purpose except this type of query. :-)

Comment: Right 'o. You say you've tried wrapping the path in [ and ], have you tried quotes instead, just for completeness? Also, (straw grasping,) the error message only shows a single \ before the server name - typo? or maybe it needs doubling up?

Comment: @shunty: I've tried both double quotes and the [] pair, and single and double \\ as the first part of the UNC (two is correct, but I was grabbing at straws). No escaping (unnecessary doubling) needed; the code is executing in Delphi via a TDataSet descendant (`TAdsQuery`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are encountering a change with the proprietary locking.  A change was made to Advantage Database Server to make the default behavior to completely deny access to other applications when proprietary locking is in use. You can disable that with the somewhat confusingly named [NONEXCLUSIVE PROPRIETARY LOCKING](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_non_exclusive_proprietary_locking.htm) configuration setting.  I think that if you set that configuration value to 1, then it will work as you are wanting.

After changing that configuration setting to 1 and restarting ADS, local server connections should be able to get read-only access to the DBF tables that the server has open.

Comment: Mark, the docs for that config setting say "non-Advantage applications" are affected, and I'm using ADS's own ARC32 SQL Window, so it's definitely an ADS application that's having the issue. I may just have to bite the bullet here and write my own app that lets me run the query on the server and then copy row-by-row to the local file, instead of just INSERTing into the local db with a SELECT from the server data like I did before. :-(

Comment: @KenWhite:  I don't think that documentation is accurate.  Instead of "non-Advantage applications", it should say "Applications that do not use Advantage Database Server", which includes applications using local server.

Comment: OK, if that's the case it may indeed be the issue. Now I just have to convince the server admin to manually edit the registry, which is going to be really difficult. Even the mention of doing that on a local machine makes him really nervous; he may faint at the thought of doing it on our production server. ;-) I wish the server config utility had a way of changing this setting.

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the ADS service? When it's not running it can't lock the tables. Also if locking is indeed an issue you should also have trouble copying the table file to your local machine using Explorer.

Comment: @KenWhite:  The config utility does have that config param exposed.  It should be on the "Misc. Settings" tab.

Comment: @Jens: I can't shut down the ADS service. It's running in a production environment, with 50+ machines accessing it. :-) Nice thought, though. Mark, I'll take a look at getting the change made in the config utility. Again, it may take a day or two before I can get the ADS server restarted to see if this fixes it. I'll make sure to come back here as soon as I find out, though, either way. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Mark, this appears to be it. It also seems that our server admin wasn't aware of this, but thinks it's a good change, so he won't change it. I'll still have to develop a workaround. :-( Thanks for the answer, and accepted (and +1 for following up with additional info in the comments that helped as well).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a remote ADS server (not ALS) you have to use server side aliases to get this functionality:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/extprocs/server_side_aliases.htm

Put this in an `C:\adsserver.ini` file on `MyServer` (or wherever your ADS logs are located):

```
[ServerAliases]
Data=X:\Data
```

Where `X:\Data` is the location of the `MyRemoteDB.dbf` table file.

However this will only work correctly if there is also a share or you have set the `IgnoreRights` setting:

> Server-side aliases must always be used in conjunction with the "Ignore Rights" setting of your Advantage client. See the Database Security topic for details. Failure to do so will result in file existence checks, which will use the server-side alias from the client and fail, resulting in AE_FILE_NOT_FOUND (5004) errors.

For ALS you can just use the normal Windows file sharing.

Comment: Both local and remote (not AIS) are involved. The ARC32 SQL window connection is to local server, and I'm trying to INSERT into a database using local with the content of data on the server drive. As I said, this worked under ADS Netware 9.1, but stopped with the switch to ADS Windows 9.1 and 10.10. I can open a different SQL window, connect via a server (remote) connection, and query the same database without difficulty.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem. We have ADS 11.10 running on Windows. I can query tables on the remote server using the `[\\MyServer\Data\MyRemoteDB.dbf]` syntax from an ALS connection to my local hard drive just fine. So it should work.

Comment: Hmmm... That's what I thought, but it doesn't. I get ADS Error 7008 still. I've confirmed that the ADS DLLs are the proper ones, that they match the server version (both 10.10). I've checked the ADS_ERR file, and it's indicating the same error. I can query fine if I open a server connection, but if I use the local server and try to select from a network location the error occurs every time.

Comment: Apart from NTFS security / share setup (which you ruled out) and locking issues (which should generate other error codes) I don't see any reason for the 7008, I'm out of ideas :-\.